# Properties of object returned by service not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a web page where a user can register for an account. I made a simple directive that checks if the username is already taken, and if so it should invalidate the form field.

My directive calls a PHP webservice which checks the databse and returns a JSON object with the status of that username.

My directive simply looks like this:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, c) {
    elm.bind('blur', function() {
        var result = accountService.uniqueUser(elm.val());
        console.log(result);
        console.log('A: '+result.usernameIsTaken);
    }
});
```

As you can see I do two `console.logs`. The first one returns this:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
usernameIsTaken: false
__proto__: Resource
```

So as you can see it "should" contain the property `userNameIsTaken`. But when the 2nd `console.log` is triggered then it returns:

```
A: undefined
```

Why can't I access that property like that? Why is it giving me `undefined` when the first `console.log` clearly shows that it should be in there...?

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are making an asynchronous request to the server, but expecting its result to be available immediately.

Instead, you can pass a success callback to the `$promise` object on `Resource` to handle the data once it becomes available:

```
result.$promise.then(function(data) {
   console.log(data.usernameIsTaken);
});
```